# Does Amazon Corretto use the Corretto Crypto Provider by default?

Tags: corretto

They don't list it in the [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/faqs/) but does Amazon Corretto use the Corretto Crypto Provider by default?

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear so I used [Is there a practical way to determine which JCE crypto providers are in use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101565/is-there-a-practical-way-to-determine-which-jce-crypto-providers-are-in-use/72208278#72208278)

and I don't see the Coretto listed